# Вопрос по перенаправлению пользователей на сайт и яндекс метрике

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, yandex-metrika-api

(1.Вопрос)Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы посетителям,перешедшим на сайт, в равной степени показывались разные фоновые изображения. Допустим чтобы первому пользователю,перешедшему на сайт отображалась первая картинка, второму пользователю - вторая картинка, третьему - третья картинка.Всего 4 картинки. И так циклично.

(2 Вопрос). Можно как то настроить цели в метрике, чтобы она засчитывалась,когда пользователь скачивает файл, или когда высвечивается модальное окно?

Comment: (1) Можно. `$bgs[array_rand($bgs)]`. (2) Можно. Разные ссылки.

Comment: Так будет выводить рандомные картинки, а нужно чтобы по порядку картинки изменялись,первый зашел на сайт-показывается первая картинка.второй человек -вторая картинка и так до 4 картинок а потом заново.

Comment: Скажите, а можно отследить фоновую картинку в яндекс метрике?
Заказчик хочет определить при какой фоновой картинке идет больше конверсий. Это возможно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Если циклично, то необходимо хранить данные. Например, задаете начальную точку отсчета "0"; следующий перешедший на страницу получает текущее значение +1
   На php, например

   $current = $valueFromDb + 1;
   $imgSrc = "/path/to/img/folder/".$current.".jpg";

Делаете проверку, если $valueFromDb == 1, то $current присваиваете единицу. Соответственно файлы картинок в папке именуете 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc

2. Укажите разные ссылки

Comment: Можно подробнее , стоит лендинг, поэтому там нет никакой базы данных.

Comment: Вам нужно, где-либо хранить данные о картинке, которая была показана. Для этого подойдет база данных, либо файл в который записывается текущий номер картинки.
Алгоритм я написал выше.

Comment: Я решил это уже этот вопрос.Спасибо.